# Angular loop json display data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to make a loop to display data from my json but I am blocked on how to do it, I am quite a beginner and I want to know the best way to do it.

The question is how can I display the value 'name' knowing that there are keys with different names?

Thanks in advance.

**example json**

```
{
  emptyKey: [],
  mdnCars:
  [
   {
     id: "1254",
     name: "tesla"
   }
  ],
  mdiBrand : [],
  mdnBrand:
  [
   {
     id: "1254",
     name: "renault"
   }
  ]
}
```

**ts.file**

```
  getAll() {
    this.typeService.getAllType().subscribe(result => {
      this.array = result
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at the official tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2 You need `ngFor`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the object to get the keys and the values.

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(yourArray)) {
  if(key !== 'emptyKey') {
    for(const brand in value) {
      console.log(brand);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const response = {
  emptyKey: [],
  mdnCars:
  [
   {
     id: "1254",
     name: "tesla"
   }
  ],
  mdiBrand : [],
  mdnBrand:
  [
   {
     id: "1254",
     name: "renault"
   }
  ]
};

const mdnCarsName = response.mdnCars.map(c => c.name);
// Guessing that you can also receive names in mdiBrand array
const mdiBrandsName = response.mdiBrand.map(b => b.name);
const mdnBrandsName = response.mdnBrand.map(b => b.name);

// A list of all cars and brands name, e.g: ['tesla', 'renault']
const allNames = mdnCarsName.concat(mdiBrandsName).concat(mdnBrandsName);
console.log(allNames)
```

**EDIT:**
You can also just use one loop, here i'm using `reduce` since there is already an answer using a `for`

```js
const excludedKeys = ['emptyKey']

const response = {
  emptyKey: [],
  mdnCars:
  [
   {
     id: "1254",
     name: "tesla"
   }
  ],
  mdiBrand : [],
  mdnBrand:
  [
   {
     id: "1254",
     name: "renault"
   }
  ]
};


const list =

Object.entries(response).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {

    if (excludedKeys.includes(key))
        return acc;

    // You can get just the names with map(n => n.name), here i'm returning also the id's
    acc.push(value.map(n => n));

    return acc;
}, []).flat(1);

console.log(list)
```

**EDIT 2**
I leave here a simple testable example in angular:
`app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

interface IMyResponse {
  emptyKey: any[];
  mdnCars: Item[];
  mdiBrand  : Item[];
  mdnBrand: Item[];
}

interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

function getObservable(): Observable<IMyResponse> {
  return new Observable((observer) => observer.next({
    emptyKey: [],
    mdnCars:
    [
     {
       id: "1254",
       name: "tesla"
     }
    ],
    mdiBrand : [],
    mdnBrand:
    [
     {
       id: "1254",
       name: "renault"
     }
    ]
  }));
}


@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  data: Item[];
  excludedKeys = ["emptyKey"];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    getObservable().subscribe(resp => this.data = this.transformResponse(resp));
  }

  transformResponse(response: IMyResponse): Item[] {
    return Object.entries(response).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {

      if (this.excludedKeys.includes(key)) {
          return acc;
      }

      // you can get just the names with map(n => n.name), here i'm returning also the id's
      acc.push(value.map((n: Item) => n));

      return acc;
  }, []).flat(1);
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`

```html
<h2>Names</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let d of data">
    <div>{{ d.id }} - {{ d.name }}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, isn't there a way to do a simple loop? Instead of doing one by one?

Comment: @Herge added that simple loop, see my edit section, after you got that array you can use ngFor iterating that list to display the info you need

Comment: @Herge added `EDIT 2` section which is a simple testable angular example

Answer (score 0):

You have got a typical problem to which I may have a clean and appropriate solution.

Now if you want to use `*ngFor` in Angular 2+ or `ng-repeat` in Angular, the best way would be to manipulate data as per your needs.

Taking into account your json,

```
{
  emptyKey: [],
  mdnCars:
  [
   {
     id: "1254",
     name: "tesla"
   }
  ],
  mdiBrand : [],
  mdnBrand:
  [
   {
     id: "1254",
     name: "renault"
   }
  ]
}
```

You only want to display the name from the JSON, write a helper function which can return you something like this

```
[
  {
    id: "1254",
    name: "tesla"
  },
  {
    id: "1254",
    name: "renault"
  }
]
```

After getting the above, perhaps then you can straightway use Angular's directive as per your needs.

I would have written a helper function but not sure of your JSON. Do let me know if you need it.

Happy Coding :)